# How to retrieve JSON value based on the value of a sibling element

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following JSON snippet

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "checks": 
    [   {
            "id": "8299393",
            "name": "NEW_CUSTOMER",
            "statusCode": "495"
        },

        {
            "id": "4949449",
            "name": "EXISTING_CUSTOMER",
            "statusCode": "497"
        }
       //Further values here
    ]
}
```

...how can I used Javascript to retrieve the `id` value `4949449` when I need to be sure it corresponds to the `"name":"EXISTING_CUSTOMER"` k/v pair as they are not ordered so I cannot use `res.id[0]` ?

```
//retrieve data via api call and read response into a const
const res = await response.json();

//get the id value 4949449 which corresponds to the sibling name whos value is 'EXISTING_CUSTOMER'   
const existingCustId = res.checks.name["EXISTING_CUSTOMER"].id; //doesn't work
```

Comment: res.checks is an array, of objects, you can iterate over the object and look for res.checks[i].name

Comment: `res.checks.find((o) => o.name == "EXISTING_CUSTOMER")?.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there would be only 1 `EXISTING_CUSTOMER`, you can use `Array.find()`

```js
const data = {
    "count": 4,
    "checks": 
    [   {
            "id": "8299393",
            "name": "NEW_CUSTOMER",
            "statusCode": "495"
        },

        {
            "id": "4949449",
            "name": "EXISTING_CUSTOMER",
            "statusCode": "497"
        }
       //Further values here
    ]
}

const existingUserID = data.checks.find(i => i.name === "EXISTING_CUSTOMER").id

console.log(existingUserID)
```

If more than 1, you can use `Array.filter()` to get the customers:

```js
const data = {
    "count": 4,
    "checks": 
    [   {
            "id": "8299393",
            "name": "NEW_CUSTOMER",
            "statusCode": "495"
        },

        {
            "id": "4949449",
            "name": "EXISTING_CUSTOMER",
            "statusCode": "497"
        },
        {
            "id": "5656565656",
            "name": "EXISTING_CUSTOMER",
            "statusCode": "497"
        }
       //Further values here
    ]
}

const existingUsers = data.checks.filter(i => i.name === "EXISTING_CUSTOMER")

console.log(existingUsers.map(i => i.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I typed too slowly. Harun beat me to it. :D

```js
const obj={
"count": 4,
"checks": 
[   {
        "id": "8299393",
        "name": "NEW_CUSTOMER",
        "statusCode": "495"
    },

    {
        "id": "4949449",
        "name": "EXISTING_CUSTOMER",
        "statusCode": "497"
    }
   //Further values here
]
}


console.log(obj.checks.find(e=>e.name=="EXISTING_CUSTOMER").id)
```